# Understanding sheaves for levels of a topos

Tags: category-theory, sheaf-theory, topos-theory

I've got a question about levels of a topos, modalities and sheaves. Assume we have got a level for a topos $\mathcal{E}$, which induces adjoint (co)modalities $\Box\dashv\bigcirc$.

On the nLab page for Aufhebung (https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Aufhebung), it says that a *sheaf* for this level is an object $X$ which is isomorphic to $\bigcirc X$.

Now, this modality $\bigcirc:\mathcal{E}\to \mathcal{E}$ is a modality on the objects of the topos itself, rather than being a modality on its subobject classifier—for the latter, I understand the definition of a sheaf in the Lawvere-Tierney style.

Can someone help me relate the modality $\bigcirc$ with a Lawvere-Tierney operator, and more specifically, understand how the two notions of sheaf come to coincide?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you seen https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Lawvere-Tierney+topology#ClosureOperation?

Comment: @VladimirSotirov Thank you so much, I can't believe I missed that! I think that section gives the construction I was looking for.

Comment: If you found an answer to your question, feel free to write it up and post it!